# None of the app delegates (didEnterBackground or willResignActive) are getting called on taking a screenshot

Tags: ios, objective-c, screenshot, appdelegate

I want to disable taking screenshot of a particular screen in my app (as it has some sensitive user data). But none of the app delegates are getting called when I take the screenshot of the app's screens. I googled and found this: active touches are not getting cancelled whenever the screenshot is taken after iOS 7. Also the following links mentions the same problem http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/2-different-methods-to-detect-screenshots-in-ios/
http://www.macrumors.com/2013/06/24/ios-7-disables-screenshot-interruptions-allows-users-to-secretly-take-snapchat-screenshots/

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict with a Configuration Profile, as described in [Configuration Profile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Check out the Restrictions Payload section, of the iPhone Configuration Profile Reference. The key you want is `allowScreenShot`

Comment: I know this is the correct answer but I know somehow I am missing some step...can u plz tell all the steps to sucessfuly achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Boolean Key is **allowScreenShot** for which the apple documentation says:
Optional. If set to false, users *can’t save a screenshot* of the display and are **prevented** from capturing a screen recording as well. Defaults to true.

Availability: Updated in iOS 9.0 to include screen recordings.

Comment: but where is this bool value present?..its not in the plist neither its any of the properties of my viewcontroller's view

Comment: Visit this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html